# It is The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 | Upload KeyStore for Google Play

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I was creating an upload Keystore for my flutter project. after successful command run, It was showing this warning:

```
    Enter key password for <upload>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
Re-enter new password:
[Storing C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool]

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry 
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry stan
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "key
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Program F
i                                                 The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using 
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Program
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Pro
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Pro
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\P
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -s
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkey
store -srckeystore C:\Program Files\Android\AndroiThe JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -import
keystore -srckeystore C:\Program Files\Android\AndThe JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which s an industry standard format using "keytool -impo
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -impS C:\Users\Rohit\Desktop\CIS634\multi_store_app>
im
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytoo-r
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytoodi
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an i
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore
y
pe pkcs12".
```

What to do now?
What has gone wrong?

Comment: It tells you exactly what is wrong, and what you need to do to fix it. What part of that is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the warning message, there is no functional impact on your flutter project.

Found this post where explain about the difference between **jks** and **pkcs12**.

https://github.com/pavlo-v-chernykh/keystore-go/issues/10

*This (keystore-go) library is an implementation of Encoder and Decoder for a proprietary Oracle (Sun) file format called jks. keystore tool from the jdk works with several formats: jks, jceks and pkcs12. jks was a default format till jdk9. From the jdk9 default format is pkcs12 and jks is deprecated. So this library is useful if you are working with legacy software that still using jks file format to store certificates and private keys. If you want to work with pkcs12 file format in your golang applications you need appropriate libraries (take a look at https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=pkcs12)
References:
JEP about switching to pkcs12 in jdk9 http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/229
KeyStore types supported by the keystore tool: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore
About Keystore implementation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#KeystoreImplementation
P.S. pkcs1 != jks != pkcs12 and so on. And to work with them you need appropriate implementations of a decoder and an encoder.*